# Linking 2 wifi routers to access NAS

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, nas

So I've two routers, one from EE and one from Sky. The sky one has broadband but no USB for an external HDD. The EE one has a USB port with a HDD attached, but no broadband as I've moved to sky.
I want my wifi to have both internet, and access to the NAS where I keep my music collection.
I tried a wired connection between the two routers. However now when I connect to the wifi of the EE router, I can't access the NAS any more (in windows 7, under Network. On my kindle, using ES File explorer). I also can't access the routers web page (192.168.1.1). However I can access the Sky routers web page (192.168.0.1). (Similarly if I connect to the Sky wifi, I can only access the sky router page not the EE one, and can't get to the NAS).
When there's no wired connection between the routers, when connected to the Sky wifi there's no problem in getting internet. And when connected to the EE router there's no problem accessing the NAS.
For some mysterious reason when the two routers are connected the EE one seems to just be a way of connecting to the Sky one. It looks like the one with the internet connection always becomes the master. Hence I can't access the EE hub page or the NAS, as described.
So, how can I set up the two routers so I can access internet and the NAS without changing the connection? I've spent many days on this before asking the community, I don't have much experience with this so any clear help would be great

Comment: Step 1. Buy a NAS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok this will be a little complicated but I'll make it as simple as possible.

1. Disconnect everything (You may want to power off devices too so things don't interfere as you're reconfiguring).
2. On the EE access point, change the IP of the actual device to be 192.168.0.2 (On the lan side, we don't care about the 'WAN' side - *You might find you need to set a WAN address use something like 169.254.1.1*).
3. Turn off DHCP on the EE access point
4. Run your network cable from any of the 'lan' ports on the Sky router, to any of the lan ports on the EE router.
5. You should now be able to have everything powered on, and access your sky router normally (192.168.0.1), your EE router normally (192.168.0.2) and your network connected drive however you'd normally connect to it.
6. If you need the extension of the wifi that the EE router is providing, set this up using the same SSID and key of the Sky router, and devices will just connect to which ever one has the strongest signal, otherwise turn the wireless off too as it's just generating interference.

Comment: The EE is a router too, not an accesspoint. So for this to work, the EE one needs a bogus Wan static ip address too, somewhere outside of the DHCP scope. Otherwise the device may not function correctly.

Comment: @LPChip The device will function just fine without a "bogus" IP address. Dunno what world you live in but our CPEs don't just keel over and die if the internet goes down.

Comment: Well, adding a routable address would surely be worse. I said 'AP' because that's all it's acting as in this situation. I could have said switch too but didn't because meh.

Comment: I tried to setup my router to do the same as you try and it would not allow me to make the configuration changes until a WAN address was configured.

Comment: Followed your steps, except for the edit re WAN address as it worked without (and couldn't see where to make this change). I can now connect to either Sky wifi or EE wifi and access both of the routers pages.  However I still can't access the HDD, not through the sky wifi or ee wifi, not from my windows 7 laptop nor from my kindle... I get "Windows cannot access \\Brightbox2" (thats the name of the EE router)

Comment: In windows, try using \\192.168.0.2\ - I'm not sure exactly how the router is sharing access to the drive...

Comment: I know this wasn't mentioned in the question, but there is a printer connected wirelessly to the sky router. Shortly after following your steps, 192.168.0.2 seems to have gotten assigned to the printer, because when I typed that in to get to the EE router page I ended up at the printer page. I tried changing in the sky router settings the "Starting IP address" from 192.168.0.2 to 192.168.0.5, in the hope this would force the router to reassign the printer's ip so that *0.2 would work again for the router. Seems to have worked, *0.1 is still sky, *0.2 is EE again, and the printer is now *0.11

Comment: Yeah, you might need to edit the dhcp range to not include the IP of the other router - some are sensible to notice an in use IP or not include .0.2 right away but not all i guess.

Comment: Please note before you waste 3 hours trying different configs - some routers just don't support this at all and get restarted to 10.0.0.1 base IP if they have another DHCP server on the network (they do that even without it...), in my case it was d-link dwr921 connected to funbox